# InputBox in Access keeps asking for prompt even after entering information

Tags: ms-access, textbox, report, inputbox

I have an access report with an empty textbox in it containing the command =InputBox("Enter General Manager Name"," Input").

Upon loading the report, the prompt appears and when I input text and press enter, the blank textbox gets filled in with the info I typed in.

However, the prompt then proceeds to reappear 5 more times in a row before finally going away.

Is there any way to make this stop?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there 6 records in the report RecordSource? If not, then there is something about reports that causes data to be processed more than once. Better to have input on form control and report reference that.

Comment: @June7 Yes there are 6 so that makes sense. However, I don't understand why the inputbox related to the amount of records in the report. Could you explain this at all?

Comment: My guess is it has to populate the textbox for each record as record loads and is rendered to report so it must ask for each record. Use a control on form for input and it will look there. Alternative is to put the input popup as a calculated field in query and bind textbox to that field `SELECT table.*, [enter value] AS F1 FROM table;`. I never use popup inputs in query because they cannot be validated.

Comment: if you put the textbox with the  call to the InputBox function in the details of the report, it will be called for every record. A better approach is to call the Imputbox from a form, and then open de report filtering by the specified name